# How do i add quick filters to the admin grids?

Tags: filter, magento2.3.0, order-grid

I've been trying to add a new filter category for an already existing column when I discovered the existence of Quick Filters.

My question is twofold:

is Quick Quickfilters compatible with the backend and, if so, how do I get them / add them to my Magento install?

Any help would be appreciated, as I've been frustrated by this for a while.